# Retrieve information from twitter account

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to create code to return information from my twitter account. I am using tweetPy api. The code I used is the following:

```
CONSUMER_KEY = "..."
CONSUMER_SECRET ="..."
OAUTH_TOKEN ="..-..."
OAUTH_SECRET ="..."
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
fp = codecs.open("Tweets.txt", "w", "utf-8")
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
  tweet.text.encode('utf8')
  fp.write(tweet.text) 
  #print (tweet.text)

 # Get the User object for twitter...
 user = tweepy.api.get_user("twitter")  

 print user.screen_name
 print user.followers_count
 for friend in user.friends():
     print friend.screen_name
```

I ve got two problems. First one, I am able to write tweet.text to a file but I am getting error when I am trying to print the result. I am getting:

```
    print (tweet.text)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The second problem in the line user = tweepy.api.get_user('username'), I am trying to return frient_list of my account, however I am getting :

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Bad Authentication data', u'code': 215}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Unicode error, better use Unicode by default in your Python script because Twitter uses Unicode character set. For that you can do the following at the start of your Python script -

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

For `Bad Authentication data` error, replace the following line -

```
user = tweepy.api.get_user("twitter")
```

with

```
user = api.get_user("twitter")
```

It should work now.